Could not find the correct Provider<XYZ> above this Builder Widget
i am new to Flutter and Bloc.
I created a dummy budgeting application consisting of 2 lists views; income and expense, in which the respective lists will get populated depending on what the user saves (e.g. clicking on a button will display a form in which they'll select if it's an income or an expense theyre entering and the amount, once saved, the relevant list will get populated.)
I have now followed a video tutorial on how to create an 'Onboarding' journey within the application.
The issue I am facing now is upon the user saving their income/expense by clicking on the save button on the form, I get the following error:
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown while handling a gesture:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<FinanceBloc> above this Builder Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- You added a new provider in your `main.dart` and performed a hot-reload.
  To fix, perform a hot-restart.

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.

- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

  Make sure that Builder is under your MultiProvider/Provider<FinanceBloc>.
  This usually happens when you are creating a provider and trying to read it immediately.

A few things to note:
- To display the onboarding screen, i have had to change the way my application runs, previously it was:
    void main() {
        Bloc.observer = const GlobalApplicationObserver();
        runApp(MyApp());
    }

but now it's:
    void main() {
        Bloc.observer = const GlobalApplicationObserver();
        runApp(MaterialApp(home: OnboardingPageWidget()));
    }

MyApp() is essentially a DefaultTabController with 1 tab at the moment and the page the tab displays is the screen with 2 lists. It's in this class's build method that is returning a BlocProvider and in the build method is the tab controller page/
This is my onboarding class:
import 'package:budgetapplication/main.dart';
import 'package:budgetapplication/repository/expenditure_repository.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//This is a private class
class _OnboardingPageState extends State<OnboardingPageWidget> {
  final PageController controller = PageController();
  bool isLastPage = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80),
          child: PageView(
            controller: controller,
            onPageChanged: (index) {
              setState(() {
                isLastPage = index == 1;
              });
            },
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Page 1'),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text('Page 2'),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomSheet: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              isLastPage
                  ? TextButton(
                      child: Text('Finish!'),
                      onPressed: () async {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()));
                      },
                    )
                  : TextButton(
                      child: Text('Next'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        controller.nextPage(
                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                            curve: Curves.bounceInOut);
                      },
                    )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class OnboardingPageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State<OnboardingPageWidget> createState() => _OnboardingPageState();
}

My suspicion is that due to the routing, the context is being lost? Not sure but any help will be greatly appreciated!

I hope I understand this correctly, and I believe it might help you.
Before you use BLoC values, you need to add the provider like this:
 void main() {
 Bloc.observer = const GlobalApplicationObserver();

 runApp(
   BlocProvider(
   create: (context) => FinanceBloc(),  // Create your FinanceBloc
   child: MyApp(),  // Your main app widget
  ),
 );
}

By adding the provider like this, you can use this BLoC throughout the entire widget tree. You can customize it later as per your requirements for better performance.make sure to hot reload after adding new bloc provider
But in simple words, you have to add the provider first, and then you can use it:
onPressed: () {
 final financeBloc = BlocProvider.of<FinanceBloc>(context);
 // Use your financeBloc here
 },

let me know you still have this error
